# Multiple Sprint boot configurations

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, gradle

I have two classes with main method in my Spring Boot application.
1. XYZToolApplication
2. XYZWebApplication
Both of them extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Both are annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and `@Configuration`.

I am using Gradle as build tool.
I want to do two things:
1. Run `XYZWebApplication` using `bootRun` and war deployment.
2. Run `XYZToolApplication` using only `bootRun` whenever a command line argument `args` is supplied with `bootRun` command.

I modified the `build.gradle` as :

```
bootRun {
    main = 'com.XYZWebApplication'
    if ( project.hasProperty('args') ) {
        main = 'com.XYZToolApplication'
        args project.args.split('\\s+')
    }
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + configurations.dev
    jvmArgs = ["-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS"]
}

war {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                    "Implementation-Title": project.name,
                    "Implementation-Version": version,
                    "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date())
        }
    }
    archiveName 'xyz.war'
}
```

While I'm able to run bootRun as desired, but when I create a war archive and deploy it to Tomcat8, there are two contexts created, one for `XYZWebApplication` and one for `XYZToolApplication`. I can see this in logs(catalina.out). I want only `XYZWebApplication` context to be created.

Snap of logs:

```
...
2017-09-15 19:20:59.209  INFO 23727 --- [ost-startStop-1] XYZWebApplication : Started XYZWebApplication in 7.677 seconds (JVM running for 10.57)  
....
2017-09-15 19:21:01.197  INFO 23727 --- [ost-startStop-1] XYZToolApplication : Started XYZToolApplication in 1.983 seconds (JVM running for 12.557)
```

I have tried specifying main class in `springBoot` task and/or `bootRepackage` task and/or `war` task, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs of `SpringBootServletInitiaizer`:

> An opinionated WebApplicationInitializer to run a SpringApplication
>   from a traditional WAR deployment. Binds Servlet, Filter and
>   ServletContextInitializer beans from the application context to the
>   servlet container.
>   If you are using SpringBootServletInitializer in
>   combination with other WebApplicationInitializers you might also want
>   to add an @Ordered annotation to configure a specific startup order.
>   **Note that a WebApplicationInitializer is only needed if you are
>   building a war file and deploying it. If you prefer to run an embedded
>   container then you won't need this at all.**

So all I did was to not extend `SpringBootServletInitiaizer` for the `XYZToolApplication` because I don't want to build a war and deploy it with this context.